# How can I post json data from sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: 2013, rest, designer-workflow

How can I post json data from share point designer work flow ?

Currently I am stuck with pass or post json data from workflow designer for sending email.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you want to post the json data?Where do you want to post that data?Can you provide more clarification?

Comment: I want to pass multiple item (Let's say multiple Email and body part of email) from workflow to External web service/Web API to send email. Thanks